# Render HTML inside Lightning string output

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

In an error message I'm writing with Lightning components, I have a phone number for customer support:

**Component:**

```
<div id="sldsErrorPanel" class="slds-has-error slds-hide" role="alert">
  <div id="sldsValidationMessage" class="slds-text-body_small slds-error-text"></div>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
validateInput : function(component, event, helper) {   
  helper.authenticateCredentials(component, helper);
},

validateInput : function (component, event, helper) {

  ...

  if (allValid) {
    $A.enqueueAction(component.get("c.validateInput"));
    return;
  }
}
```

**Helper:**

```
authenticateCredentials: function(component, helper) {      

  var accountLocked = "Your account has been locked. Please call us at 800-MY-NUMBER to unlock your account.";

  ...

}
```

I want to be able to make the phone number a link, an `a href="tel:"` element in the output so VoIP and mobile users can click the link and call, e.g.,

```
var accountLocked = "Your account has been locked. Please call us at <a href="tel:800-123-4567">800-MY-NUMBER</a> to unlock your account.";
```

I don't see anything in Lightning that allows me to do that. Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried splitting your string and using [**lighting:formattedPhone**](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedPhone/example) here?

Comment: You can also try lighnting:clickToDial . https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:clickToDial/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleClickToDial

Comment: Thank you. It looks like :formattedPhone and :clickToDial aren't added to an outputted string.

Comment: @MattSmith can you provide your component code, as how you are trying to render this value? The values need to be in their specific tags, so I would imagine that having it on the component something as [Your account has been locked ... <lightning:formattedPhone> ... rest of the text] should work.

Comment: @JayantDas, I added a snippet of the code. I may need to just add it with static text in the component if I can't dynamically add it in the controller/helper.

Comment: @MattSmith I provided a possible approach, that can help you here. It will address both static/dynamic values to be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there can be different ways to achieve this, but with what you are trying to achieve, I would have broken the string in different variables, and utilized the [lightning:formattedPhone](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedPhone/example) as below.

**1**. Declare 3 different attributes on my component, something as below

```
<aura:attribute name="myText1" type="String" default="Your account has been locked. Please call us at "></aura:attribute>
<aura:attribute name="myText2" type="String" default="800-MY-NUMBER"></aura:attribute>
<aura:attribute name="myText3" type="String" default=" to unlock your account."></aura:attribute>
```

**2**. Populate these fields in my JS controller/helper with any **dynamic** text

```
component.set("v.myText1", <first part of the text goes here>);
component.set("v.myText2", <phone number goes here>);
component.set("v.myText3", <last part of the text goes here>);
```

**3**. So that it finally, renders as below on my component:

```
{!v.myText1} <lightning:formattedPhone value="{!v.myText2}"></lightning:formattedPhone> {!v.myText3}
```

[image]